# Ways to synchronize Android smartphone

Tags: android

How can I synchronize over the air my Android smartphone and laptop? I'm interested in file sharing, notifications from phone, if it possible.

Answer (score 5):

For these purposes, the most suitable [KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) in combination with [KDE Connect Indicator](https://github.com/vikoadi/indicator-kdeconnect).

> KDE Connect is a project that aims to communicate all your devices. For example, with KDE Connect you can receive your phone notifications on your computer, or just use your phone as a remote control for your desktop. To achieve this, KDE Connect implements a secure communication protocol over the network, and allows any developer to create plugins on top of it. Currently there are KDE Connect clients on KDE, Android and Blackberry, and soon we will support iPhone as well.

Features:

- display notifications from your Android device on your desktop (requires Android 4.3+);
- send files from your Android device to your desktop and the other way around "without wires";
- touchpad emulation: use your phone screen as your computer's touchpad (keyboard emulation is also available);
- shared clipboard between your phone and computer;
- display your phone's battery status on the desktop;
- multimedia remote control: use your Android device to control various Linux media players;
- RSA Encryption.

Install (carefully, a lot dependencies of KDE):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vikoadi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect --no-install-recommends
```

Then you need to install the application on your phone from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/app/org.kde.kdeconnect_tp).

After run **KDE Connect Indicator** from laucnher and follow the instructions.

[image]

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/kde-connect-indicator-use-kde-connect.html).

Comment: This comes with a **huge** number of KDE dependencies in elementary, even the breeze-theme and such. If one wants to see what that installs the `--no-install-recommends` argument **should not be used**. There is no space in a comment to display all that, [here it is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PXr40pbR), but at the end it says `Need to get 107 MB of archives.
After this operation, 442 MB of additional disk space will be used.`

Answer (score 2):

You also use Pushbullet to a good sync of all your Android gadgets and Linux desktop.

You can find more information about it at

[Pushbullet site](https://www.pushbullet.com)

In elementary OS, you must install Pushbullet-indicator with the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install pushbullet-indicator
```

Before run it, you must install Pushbullet app for Android and sign in with your Google account:

[Pushbullet app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android)