# Connecting an Android 5.1 device - unable to detect the device

Tags: release-freya, android

I'm using Freya for a month and I connected my Xperia Z2 tablet (Android 5.0.1) and LG G3 (Android 5.0) several times before, just to manage files (music, videos). It worked just the way as it works while connecting a USB flash disk.

After upgrading my Xperia Z2 tablet to Android 5.1, Freya does not recognize the connected device at all. The tablet works as usually, it shows the connection menu etc., but there is no device recognized in folders.

When trying to connect the tablet to my PC running Win10, it works fine as before the upgrade.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Try to use KDEConnect, it's more convenient than using wires. More: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1156/160

Answer (score 1):

On your tablet, go to Settings > Xperia Connectivity > USB Connectivity and select MSC as USB mode. Sony does not ship the MTP drivers for Linux.