# Cannot access Android device from Pantheon Files ("Unable to Mount Folder")

Tags: pantheon-files, android

When I try to access my phone (Samsung Galaxy J2) or tablet (Nexus 9 WiFi) from pantheon files I get a message saying `Cannot Mount Folder`

[image: cannot mount]

And it is also the same with the tablet (Nexus 9). I can access them from Windows and other Linux distros but not from elementary OS

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting with MTP? Install `mtpfs` with `sudo apt install mtpfs`.

You can also use [KDE Connect](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1145/5565) to communicate between your device and computer.

If that doesn't work, this isn't the only report we've seen of Android phone/tablet detection issues in Files, so I've [reopened the issue in our bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1346264). Please follow its progress there in case the devs need more information, but I'll also report back here.